# The table-striped class is not giving me alternate color

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I was hoping to have alternating color for my table. However, all rows become grey after I applied the table-striped class. I tried to load both v3 and v4 boostrap css files. And it still didn't work.

## html

```
    <table id="maxDiversificationTable" class="investmentTable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-fit" style="margin-top:-55%" >
        <thead>
            <tr style="color:#337AC7" >
                <th >Tickers</th>
                <th >Current Weight</th>
                <th >New Weight</th>
                <th >Conviction</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for tableData in dataSet %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{tableData.tickers}}</td>
                <td>{{tableData.currentWeight}}</td>
                <td>{{tableData.newWeight}}</td>
                <td>{{tableData.conviction}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
    
    </table>
```

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that your `<tbody>` which is also inside your for loop. So, your table is rendered like this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <td>{{tableData.tickers}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.currentWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.newWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.conviction}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <td>{{tableData.tickers}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.currentWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.newWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.conviction}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Which is not what you want. What you want is the following:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <td>{{tableData.tickers}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.currentWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.newWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.conviction}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>{{tableData.tickers}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.currentWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.newWeight}}</td>
       <td>{{tableData.conviction}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

So, try taking `tbody` out of the for loop and see if it works:

```
<tbody>
    {% for tableData in dataSet %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{tableData.tickers}}</td>
            <td>{{tableData.currentWeight}}</td>
            <td>{{tableData.newWeight}}</td>
            <td>{{tableData.conviction}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

The `table-striped` class is defined in Bootstrap 4's SCSS as follows:

```
.table-striped {
  tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: $table-bg-accent;
  }
}
```

So, in essence, the `$table-bg-accent` color will be applied to every odd row (`tr`) in every table body (`tbody`) element. Since you're creating a new table body for every row, every row will have the accent color applied.

To fix, don't create a new `tbody` for every row:

```html
<thead>
  <tr style="color:#337AC7">
    <th>Tickers</th>
    <th>Current Weight</th>
    <th>New Weight</th>
    <th>Conviction</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for tableData in dataSet %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{tableData.tickers}}</td>
    <td>{{tableData.currentWeight}}</td>
    <td>{{tableData.newWeight}}</td>
    <td>{{tableData.conviction}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```